# Update reducer state from form input tag?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am trying to update input tag value to the redux-reducer.

Here's my code:

My action created:

```
export const addName = text => ({
  type:'Add Name',
  text
})
```

My reducer component is:

```
export default  function() {
  return { firstName: " "}
}
```

My final index.js is:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import rootReducer from "./reducers/name";
import { createStore } from "redux";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

let store = createStore(rootReducer)

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,

  document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

And my presentational component where form is:

```
import React,{Component} from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { addName } from "./actions";
class App extends Component {
  inputData = (event) =>
  {
    this.setState({
      [event.target.name]:event.target.value
    });
  }
  submitData = (event) =>
  {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.props.firstName)
    dispatch(addName(this.input.value))
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <form>
          FirstName:
          <input type="text" name={this.props.firstName} onChange={this.inputData}/>
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
        {this.props.firstName}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
function mapStateToProps(dispatch)
{
  return{
    firstName: state.firstName
  };
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
```

I simply want to take value from input field and then onSubmit button I want to update reducer firstName to be updated...
please help with this issue.......

I followed redux todo app example but didn't able to make any connection....

Answer (score 0):

You are probably getting error in the console about `dispatch` method.

In `submitData` method Change

```
dispatch(addName(this.input.value))
```

to

```
this.props.dispatch(addName(this.input.value))
```

Edit:

In your `mapStateToProps` function, you are expecting `dispatch` and in definition you are accessing `state.firstName`. Change argument to `state` as below:

```
function mapStateToProps(state)
{
  return{
    firstName: state.firstName
  };
}
```

Comment: That error is removed, but name is not printing when I submit!

Comment: @YashChoksi I have updated my answer, please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

your action creator should look like the following code:

```
export const setName = action => {
    type: "SET_NAME",
    action
}
```

and reducer looks like the following code:

```
export const FormReducer = (state = initState, action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case "SET_NAME":
           return {...state, name: action.name}
        default:
           return state
    }
}
```

and in your component better than to pass actions to props look like the following code:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        actions: bindActionCreators(actions, dispatch)
    }
}    
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

in fact, you should `import * as action from your action creator :)`

and on form submit write following code:

```
this.props.actions.setName({name:event.target.value})
```

Comment: It shows some error:
  Line 33:  'bindActionCreators' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 33:  'actions' is not defined             no-undef

Comment: you should `import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'`

Comment: Still some other errors: 
 Line 34:  'actions' is not defined          no-undef
  Line 37:  'mapStateToProps' is not defined  no-undef

Comment: @YashChoksi Good luck

Comment: I gone through your code, you mentioned at many places "...action" and many other like this, what is the meaning of these 3 dots??

Comment: that is Spread syntax: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax